# OData entity property serialization name different than C# variable name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

In an ASP .NET Web API using OData, I have a C# object describing the fields allowed to be used in $filter

Say I want to limit `$filter` support to only `$filter=deviceId gt 'someValue'` (followed http://www.ben-morris.com/parsing-odata-queries-decoupled-data-entities-webapi/ approach...).

So I defined a class like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class DeviceODataQuery
{
    [DataMember(Name = "deviceId")]
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
}
```

Then I build myself the OData context because I can't use `IQueryable` (too long to explain why, its legacy code...).

It looks like this:

```
/* Configure supported fields for query */
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<DeviceODataQuery>("DeviceODataQuery");
builder.Namespace = typeof(DeviceODataQuery).Namespace;
var model = builder.GetEdmModel();
ODataQueryContext = new ODataQueryContext(model, typeof(DeviceODataQuery));

/* Configure supported OData parameters for validation */
ODataValidationSettings.AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.None;
ODataValidationSettings.AllowedLogicalOperators = AllowedLogicalOperators.GreaterThan;
ODataValidationSettings.AllowedArithmeticOperators = AllowedArithmeticOperators.None;
ODataValidationSettings.AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.Top | AllowedQueryOptions.Filter;
```

Long story short, I can now use `$filter=DeviceId gt 'someValue'` in my requests, but it rejects using the name from the annotation, I cannot use `deviceId`...

It seems like the annotations are ignored, is there another way to do it or fix my code to make annotations working?

Comment: Have you tried DataContract / DataMember attributes?

Comment: I tried with no luck, the annotations are ignored. Editing the question to include this.

Comment: Actually I am using Nuget package OData v1-3 and not v4, that is the root cause of the issue. OData v4 nuget package supports aliasing.

Comment: I'm using V4 and its not working